# Forward every third email to a given person

Tags: vba, outlook, server-side, rules

I need something (script, rule) that would forward every *third* email that comes to my account to some other email address. But I need this to be able to run even when the Outlook/PC is closed/ turned off.
Is it possible to do that?

It's third message to one given person. So every message counts as "third" 
                - first go to person A, second to person B and third to person C, fourth to person A, fifth to person B etc etc...

Well if I could manage to create the script being server side I would imagine doing something like:
do 3 rules:

1. Received message = Send message to person A, delete it, turn rule 2
   on and turn itself off
2. Received message = Send message to person B,
   delete it, turn rule 3 on and turn itself off
3. Received message =
   Send message to person C, delete it, turn rule 1 on and turn itself
   off

This should work, I just don't know if it is possible to make it server-side so Outlook doesn't have to be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would only be possible with a client side rule, which will not run when Outlook is not running. So, no, you cannot do that.